# How to set second material to a second submesh in a combined mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have this code (not originally my invention) that is working fine, but I have hit upon a problem with it. I can't seem to render the second submesh, with another material.

I can't figure out the problem lies in [renderer] part or the 2nd "submesh" that is perhaps never combining.

```
@script RequireComponent(MeshFilter)
@script RequireComponent(MeshRenderer)
private var matarray : Material[] = new Material[2];
var mat : Material;
var mat2 : Material;

function Start () {
    matarray[0] = mat;
    matarray[1] = mat2;

    for (var child in transform)
        child.position += transform.position;
    transform.position = Vector3.zero;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

    var meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren(MeshFilter);
    var combine : CombineInstance[] = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length-1];
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < meshFilters.Length; i++) {
        if (meshFilters[i].sharedMesh == null)
            continue;
        combine[index].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
        combine[index++].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
        renderer.sharedMaterials = matarray;
        meshFilters[i].active = false;
    }
    GetComponent(MeshFilter).mesh = new Mesh();
    GetComponent(MeshFilter).mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);
    renderer.active = true;

    //here seems to be the trouble.
    renderer.sharedMaterials = matarray;
}
```

Alternatively I have tried,

```
renderer.sharedMaterials[1] = matarray[1];
```

In short, I'm in trouble. I have to save few draw calls, which is not looking good unless this gets fixed.

Comment: Removed "Tags: ..." from title. Added tag unityscript.

Comment: Those were neccessary